# Is it possible to change encoding of multiple files using sublime text 2

Tags: encoding, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I've tried key bindings, like this one -

```
{
 "keys" : ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"],
 "command" : "save_all", "args" :{"encoding" : "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)"}
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. Do User Key Bindings work at all in your setup?

Comment: yeah, if i put just "save" instead of "save_all"  that works perfect.